# How do I control with roles can use a bot on my Discord server?

Tags: permissions, bot, discord

What do the "Roles & Members" settings (*Server Settings > Integrations > [BOT_NAME] > Roles & Members*) for a bot do? I would have thought that this was the way to control which users can use a bot's `/` commands, but that's not what happens. For example, if I just have the `@everyone` role listed for a bot and click the red X, I can still use the bot.

What does this setting do, and how do I prevent a user or role from using a bot, or restrict use of a bot to specific roles or users?

Answer (score 2):

It's not very intuitive, but these settings are for "slash commands" which were introduced recently, within the past few years. Many bots don't use them, and instead read all the messages they can access looking for ones that match a certain pattern. For example, one bot uses `!` as its prefix, so that's `!` + command + arguments: `!roll 1d20`.

Examples of slash commands are `/nick` and `/me`. These particular ones are not from a bot but from Discord itself.

You can see the slash commands below if an integration has any or "this application has no commands":

[image: On Command Permissions page, under "channels"]

The only way to restrict who can a bot with no slash commands is to make sure that users can't post in the channels it's allowed to read, or by using the tools that the bot itself gives for managing permissions.

See more at [Command Permissions](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/4644915651095-Command-Permissions)